# Can bribing a guarded foe gain friendship?

Tags: civilization-5

I am in the late game and there is a power triangle. The usually technological superior foe, Korea is out in front with the Aztec and myself (Incan) vying for victory.

The Aztecs are guarded and Korea is friendly. I wish to turn that around. I want Korea to hate me and Aztec to like me.

So I am now in the process of doing the following.

- Stopping trade with Korea or any kind.
- Telling them off for attacking a city state.
- Publicly denounce Korea
- I have gifted Aluminium to the Aztec.

Is there anything else I can do?

For fun, I wondered if the following would work. Even though Aztec is at war with Korea, he would not accept this.
[image]

Comment: The AI is somewhat mysterious, but it seems to be more impacted by things like who you've declared war on in the past far, far more than any type of trade relations you've had.  I've gifted major resources to the AI in the past and seen almost no change in its attitude towards me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess based on previous Civ games is that the relationship bonus that you can gain from a gift is capped at a relatively small amount.  So while it will move you in the right direction, you won't be able to buy your way out of any situation.  I'll try to see if I can verify from the Diplomacy screen.

Comment: I believe you are correct. So far my bribes have not have much effect. Hovering over monte does not say anything like "Oh we love you for the glorious gifts you bestow!"

Answer (score 2):

If you hover over guarded / friendly via the indivdual diplomacy window, It will actually tell you what is contributing to this state of relationship. Green denotes good things, red is bad.

So save it, Bribe them or do anything else you wish to try, then see if it has benefited in anyway. If not, just load it or continue.

[image]

Comment: Yah, but it doesn't tell you how much each thing counts for, like it used to in Civ 4.  Clearly bribing is a good thing, the question is how much.  So you can't really determine the answer to the original question.

Comment: Another place to hover. thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Bribe your friendly Koreans to attack the unfriendly Aztec for a few turns. They'll eventually realize that being friends with you isn't worth their time (any may backstab you), and it'll distract both opponents for ten turns, reducing their military progress, which will weaken their economy and scientific progress.